# Select Query taking very large time to get executed

Tags: postgresql

We have a [View](https://ideone.com/99l3U7) and we run a very simple query on it:

```
select * from VIEW limit 10;
```

This query runs in less than 5 secs on Oracle but takes more than an hour to get executed on PostgreSql.

Also this query results "division by 0" error in Postgres but not in Oracle. On psql command line too it takes same amount of time.

Could someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you have security issues for sending view query, just rename columns and show us the logic behind the query.I have really no idea  what can cause division by zero in a SQL query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes and the view definition)  and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** - not a simple `explain`! [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour: a simple `select 1 / (select count(*) from some_table where false)` would do - most probably there is some aggregation in the view that does something like that.

Comment: If you can't expose table names, you can e.g. upload the execution plan to https://explain.depesz.com/ and use the "obfuscation" option for it

Comment: The query is pretty big. And the problem is the query doesn't get executed even for an hour and the execution plan is also not generated.
I ll try and post a dummy query resembling it.

Comment: Then at least show the output of `explain (verbose)` (which doesn't run the query). But without the tables and the view definition this will be impossible to answer

Comment: I have added the dummy query having the same structure. The joins at the end don't do any division operations.
I also tried to execute the query with explain in DBeaver but that also didn't get executed.